# How do I append an int vector to a factor?

Tags: r, vector, append, r-factor

I have a matrix called matrix that looks like this:

```
charge  convexhull_xCoor    convexhull_yCoor    id              intensity
3       3336.43             667.62       f_7936733956214261295  475891
3       3339.73             667.6        f_7936733956214261295  475891
```

I get two vectors, id and intensity:

```
idVector = matrix[4]
intensityVector = matrix[5]
```

I want to add these two vectors together using append:

```
bigVector = append(idVector, intensityVector)
```

However, when I do this I get this as a result:

```
[1]       4       3       2       1  475891 5490000 1860000 1100000
```

R made a class = factor out of the idVector and when I appends the intVector to it, it is not appending it to the labels. How can I append an int vector to a factor?

Below is the reproducible code, I only have trouble giving the dput(head(matrix,4)) because it gives all the id's which are quite a lot, I gave the dput(head(matrix,4)) of the vectors instead.

```
vector1 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("f_15177294341548527346", "f_18178836531573487427", "f_2444900193131259878", "f_7936733956214261295"), class = factor")
vector2 = c(475891, 5490000, 1860000, 1100000)
bigVector = append(vector1, vector2)
vector1
vector2
bigVector
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix factors & numbers like that in a vector - you have to use a data frame.

```
bigdf <- data.frame( id=idVector, intensity=intensityVector )
```

Then have a look at `bigdf` (and you can access columns via `bigdf$id`, etc).

Alternatively, **if the elements of `idVector` are unique**, you could add `idVector` as the names attribute of your `intensityVector`:

```
names(intensityVector) <- idVector
```

However the id is no longer a factor, but you can refer to values in `intensity` by a particular `id` as in `intensityVector['f_7936733956214261295']`.

The data frame approach is almost always better because it's very well-suited to statistical analysis.

Comment: The datafrane solution makes an int out of the identity and then rounds them up like this: f_16392539553645958321
 becomming 1640000000.0. I need the whole identifier to match the id to another vector with the same id's.

Comment: It shouldn't make them an int in the data frame, are you sure `idVector` is 'f_xxxxx' as opposed to ints? As a last resort you could do `id=as.character(idVector)` but that shouldn't be necessary if `idVector` is already characters.